# How can I retrieve the Geolocation from an IP address in Grails?

Tags: spring, grails, geolocation, grails-2.0

I want to retrieve the geolocation from an IP-address in a Grails app.

I tried [hostip](http://grails.org/plugin/hostip) and [geoip](http://grails.org/plugin/geoip) both raise exceptions and did not work for me. Is there any other way to get the geolocation?

When I use geoip I have:

config.groovy:

```
geoip.data.resource= "/WEB-INF/GeoLiteCity.dat"
geoip.data.cache="GEOIP_STANDARD"
```

In my controller:

```
GeoIpService geoIpService

index() {
    def location = geoIpService.getLocation("85.176.52.75")
    render location.countryName + " " + location.city       
}
```

The exception is:

```
| Error 2013-07-26 14:04:22,236 [http-bio-8090-exec-1] ERROR   
errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - NullPointerException occurred when processing request:   [GET] /test/home/index
Stacktrace follows:
Message: null
Line | Method
->>  199 | <init>                    in java.util.StringTokenizer
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    221 | <init>                    in     ''
|    624 | getLocationwithdnsservice in com.maxmind.geoip.LookupService
|    593 | getLocation               in     ''
|     42 | getLocation . . . . . . . in org.grails.geoip.service.GeoIpService
|     12 | index                     in test.HomeController
|    195 | doFilter . . . . . . . .  in    
grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter                  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run                       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: What exception did you get for geoip?  We use it in our java/spring app with no problems.

Comment: @JohnFarrelly I put the exception in my question. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure your DAT file hasn't been corrupted?  Maybe redownload it?

Comment: I used on http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/ the GeoLite City > Binary / gzip file. Is this what you have used too?

Comment: Yeah, it's more or less the same file.  Is it definitely the uncompressed file you're using?

Comment: Yes I use the uncompressed version: GeoLiteCity.dat. Can you share your config and code sample I can test?

Comment: Interestingly, I just downloaded the city dat file and got a parsing exception while using it - I don't get an exception using the country file.  Maybe try that one and see if it at least gets passed the parsing problems? http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz

Comment: Can you send me the file which worked for you for city and country?

Comment: The one I linked to in my previous comment is the one that works for me: http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz

Comment: can formulate it as a answer then I can accept you comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After downloading your sample grails app from github, and after debugging it for a while, I found out what the problem is.  Well, there are 2 problems really:

- Your configuration for the geoip plugin is incorrect
- The documentation for the geoip plugin makes it look like the configuration you have is correct, when it is not.

If you take a look at the documentation for the plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/geoip you will see that it talks about the configuration for the `geoip.data.cache` as follows:

```
geoip.data.cache - There are 4 possible values for this:
0 - GEOIP_STANDARD
1 - GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE
2 - GEOIP_CHECK_CACHE
4 - GEOIP_INDEX_CACHE
```

So what it is actually looking for is the **integer** values, not the strings beside them.  For example, 0 is used for GEOIP_STANDARD, so you configure it with:

```
geoip.data.cache=0
```

When I changed the configuration of your sample app to the above, I no longer get the exceptions.

Comment: I tried what you said, but it results in the same error as before. I created a sample project to show you what I mean. You will find the project here: https://github.com/confile/geoip Just start the project and you will see the error. I did exactly what you said.

Comment: Yes thank you. It is also working with the GeoLiteCity.dat file.